# How to set Chrome experimental option in C# Selenium?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

How can I set a Chrome "experimental option" in Selenium, in C#? Specifically, I'm trying to set the recent http-auth-committed-interstitials flag to Disabled. I've tried various things with ChromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability() & ChromeOptions.AddArguments(), but nothing has worked. Or, if something *did* work, I can't find a way *tell* it worked, i.e. to determine that the option was actually set.

Or, if there's a way to set experimental options on the command line, that would work too, since I can hopefully use the general-purpose ChromeOptions.AddArguments().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this looking for the answer like I did...

The way to do this is

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddLocalStatePreference("browser", new { enabled_labs_experiments = new string[] { "http-auth-committed-interstitials@2" } });
```

The value is normally read from the LocalState file in your UserData directory. In the above code example the value you are trying to set is placed in the string array in the form of "value@option" where 'value' is the name of the experimental feature and 'option' is either 1 for enable, or 2 for disabled.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what's your env.
But in my env set:

```
[options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);]
```

It works.